# How does De Moivre work, when $n$ is even?

Tags: complex-analysis

How does De Moivre work, when $n$ is even?

Consider e.g. $z^8=1$.

Then by De Moivre

$$z^n=r^n(\cos(n \theta)+ i \sin(n \theta))$$

For $n=8$. This is satisfied by:

$$r \in \{-1, 1\}$$

$$\theta_{1,2,...,8}=\frac{2 k \pi}{8}$$

However, this would give 16 solutions. When we only look for 8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should only have $r=1$. The co-ordinates in polar form will always have non-negative length; in your case, $r=-1$ is accounted for by one of the values of $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

No, just $8$. You counted them all twice; for example $$(-1)e^{i\pi}=(1)e^{i0}.$$